# Responsive Text

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have some problems with making a responsive website. I want to make footer be like header but i cant handle it. I've tried many ways but im not very good at making websites. Please help if you can guys what should i use to make that footer responsive to all sizes.

Here are my index.html and style.css

```css
    body {
 font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 /*padding: 0;*/
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.container {
 width: 80%;
 margin: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}

img { 
 padding-right: 55%;
 padding-top: 22%;
 /*width: 13%;*/
 min-height: 10%;
 }

.access { 
 transform: translate(-1%, -150%);
  }

header { 
 background: #14a79d;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 min-height: 70px;
 margin-right: 18%;
 margin-left: 18%;
 border-top-left-radius: 25px;
 border-top-right-radius: 25px;
 }

.footer { 
 position: relative;
 background: #14a79d;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 margin-right: 10%;
 margin-left: 10%;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
 }

.box {
 text-align: center;
 background-color: white;
 height: 78vh;
 background-size: cover;
 margin-left: 10%;
 margin-right: 10%;
}

/*footer {*/
 /*position: fixed;*/
 /*overflow: auto;*/
 /*padding: 0 20px;*/
 /*left: 0;*/
 /*bottom: 0;*/
 /*right: 0;*/
 /*width: 60%;*/
 /*margin-top: 100px;*/
 /*color: #ffffff;*/
 /*background-color: #14a79d;*/
 /*text-align: center;*/
 /*line-height: 50px;*/
 /*padding: 0 20px;*/
 /*margin-right: 18%;*/
 /*margin-left: 18%;*/
 /*height: 100%;*/
 /*margin-top: -2%;*/
 /*border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;*/
 /*border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;*/
  /*}*/
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="denied">
      <h1>Access Denied</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<section id="boxes">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="x.png">
      <div class="access">

        <h1 style="color: red;">Page Blocked</h1>

        <p>You are attempting to access a forbidden Site.<br>It is blocked according to<br> the organization security policy.</p>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <p>&copy copyright ... 2018</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this? Maybe taking the footer out of the main container helps.

```css
body {
    font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header { 
    background: #14a79d;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20vh;
    margin-right: 18%;
    margin-left: 18%;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
 }

footer {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #14a79d;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 18%;
    margin-left: 18%;
    height: 10vh;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
     }

.box {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: grey;
    height: 70vh;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Access Denied</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="denied">
                <h1>Access Denied</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section id="boxes">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box">
                <img src="x.png">
                <div class="access">
                  <h1 style="color: red;">Page Blocked</h1>

                  <p>You are attempting to access a forbidden Site.<br>It is blocked according to<br> the organization security policy.</p>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <footer>
      <div class='container'>
         <p>&copy copyright ... 2018</p>
    </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for help man, it is attached now but now there is a scrollbar on the small screen and on the second much bigger screen there is a space on the bottom.

Comment: Oh do you want it to fill the entire screen for all screen sizes? Setting the height of the header and footer should do it. I'll edit my answer

Comment: thank you very much ! Do you know some websites where can i learn such things ?

Comment: Edited the answer. You may want to play around with the heights to get what to you want. To be even more responsive you can use the [@media rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). Hmm I don't have any recommendations, I usually just google everything :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  background: #14a79d;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  /*padding-top: 30px;*/
  min-height: 70px;
  margin-right: 18%;
  margin-left: 18%;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}

footer {
  /*position: fixed;*/
  /*overflow: auto;*/
  padding: 0 10px;
  /*left: 0;*/
  /*bottom: 0;*/
  /*right: 0;*/
  /*width: 60%;*/
  /*margin-top: 100px;*/
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #14a79d;
  text-align: center;
  /*margin-left: 18%;*/
  /*margin-right: 10%;*/
  /*line-height: 50px;*/
  /*padding: 0 20px;*/
  margin-right: 18%;
  margin-left: 18%;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  /*margin-top: -2%;*/
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
}

.box {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 85vh;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.footer-inner {
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: #1f5cff;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="denied">
      <h1>Access Denied</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<section id="boxes">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="x.png">
      <div class="access">
        <h1 style="color: red;">Page Blocked</h1>
        <p>You are attempting to access a forbidden Site.<br>It is blocked according to<br> the organization security policy.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="container footer-inner">
        <p class="text-center">&copy copyright ... 2018</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your help. It is working but is there any way to make it responsive, i mean that there is an scrollbar on the small screen and on the much bigger screen there is a space on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the text size with em unit,
em - Relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font)